# Excel VBA: specify fields for line chart through a variable

Tags: vba, graph

I need a help. i am creating a macro on excel to perform different charts.
I receive a message of error in the specification of the VALUES of the chart.
Since I need to create several similar charts with different X and Y values, I am specifying the ranges through a string, whose content is updated every time.
The Sheets I am working with are called "Data" and "Graph", that´s why you´ll see those names in the code.
I am using VBA on Excel 2010.

Here is the code.

```
Sub repetutive_charts()

Dim day As Integer
Dim row_in As Long
Dim row_end As Long

row_in = 3602
row_end = 90001

For day = 2 To day = 13
' Need to select an empty cell, like D1, otherwise the old graph is still selected and excel cannot create a new graph

Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).name = "=Graph!$A$" & CStr(row_in)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$K$" & CStr(row_in) & ":$K$" & CStr(row_end)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Xvalues = "=Data!$I$" & CStr(row_in) & ":$I$" & CStr(row_end)

row_in = row_in + 5400
row_end = row_end + 5400

Next day
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message? What line raises the error?  This macro works fine for me, except you need to change your loop: `For day = 2 To day = 13` should be `For day = 2 To  13`.

Comment: OMG!
I am so so sorry, I have been programming on VBA for 3 days and I had not noticed the mistake in the syntaxis of the "For Loop".

Also, I don´t get any error message anymore (?), but before it was telling me that the format type indicated in the ".Values" and ".Xvalues" was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I had made a syntaxis mistake, which David Zemens let me notice. I have just started programming in VBA, so I am not an expert with the syntaxis...

```
Sub repetutive_charts()

Dim day As Integer
Dim row_in As Long
Dim row_end As Long

row_in = 3602
row_end = 90001

For day = 2 To 13
' Need to select an empty cell, like D1, otherwise the old graph is still selected and excel cannot create a new graph

Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).name = "=Graph!$A$" & CStr(row_in)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$K$" & CStr(row_in) & ":$K$" & CStr(row_end)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Xvalues = "=Data!$I$" & CStr(row_in) & ":$I$" & CStr(row_end)

row_in = row_in + 5400
row_end = row_end + 5400

Next day
End Sub
```